# Remove foreign key from a table - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to remove a foreign key from a table with migrations

This is the table where I have the foreign key:

```
class CreatePriceWorkshops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :price_workshops do |t|
      t.float :price

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

With this migration I create the foreign key:

```
class AddTypeMoneysToPriceWorkshops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :price_workshops, :type_money, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

With this I try to remove the foreign key

```
class RemoveTypeMoneyFromPriceWorkshops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :price_workshops, :type_money_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post what error you get, with your attempt

Comment: You also do not need to pass `:integer` for type when calling `remove_column`

Answer (score 4):

```
class RemoveTypeMoneyFromPriceWorkshops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference(:price_workshops, :type_money, index: true, foreign_key: true)
  end
end
```

From official docs, check out more [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_reference)

Comment: Table 'price_workshops' has no foreign key on column 'type_money_id'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `remove_foreign_key` instead of `remove_column` as per the [official doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key)?

```
class RemoveTypeMoneyFromPriceWorkshops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :price_workshops, :type_money
  end
end
```

Comment: I know it but I do not know the correct way to use it in my problem

Comment: Table 'price_workshops' has no foreign key on column 'type_money_id'

Comment: Did you run the exact migration I provided? Do you have other migrations before this one that remove the foreign key? Are you sure the migration that was supposed to add the foreign key relationship actually ran? You know, now that I think about it, why are you explicitly adding a foreign key at all? The Rails Way is to specify referential relationships via Active Record associations like `has_one`, `belongs_to` and so on. I'm not sure, but you might be able to run `rake db:schema:dump` from the console and look in `db/schema.rb` to see if there are any columns starting with `fk_` to verify.